# StructureMap working locally, but not on production server

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

I developing a MVC5 application, where I am using StructureMap as my DI framework. The application works fine, when I run it locally from Visual Studio. However when I publish to our production server, I get the "No parameterless constructor..." error. I've Googled a solution and found a suggestion to add the code below to an empty constructor in the controller, in order to get a more detailed exception:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        _bll = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAgentStatsBll>();
    }

    private IAgentStatsBll _bll;

    public HomeController(IAgentStatsBll bll)
    {
        _bll = bll;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel {Authors = _bll.GetAuthorsWithCommentsOnDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60))};
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

When I run this code on the production server, I get an error saying:

```
No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'ZendeskAgentStats.BLL.IAgentStatsBll'. 
There is no configuration specified for ZendeskAgentStats.BLL.IAgentStatsBll
```

If I understand the error correct, it says that SM cannot figure out which concrete type it should use for the IAgentStatsBll interface. However this is configured in the DefaultRegistry.cs:
    public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

```
    public DefaultRegistry()
    {
        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<IAgentStatsBll>();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<IAgentStatsDal>();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<IAgentStatsContext>();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<ZendeskAPIMethods>();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });
        For(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Can anyone figure out why it is working locally but not on the server?

Comment: Is your production server being built by a build server somewhere? If so can you take that code and run it locally to see if it persists? Also have you fully cleaned your build in visual studio before doing a rebuild? VS can sometimes leave DLLs in your bin directory even after a clean that can cause strange effects (eg if one of these DLLs had your concrete implementation in it).

Comment: Sounds like StructureMap isn't getting configured properly.  How is your production server different?  Are you running IIS Express locally?  If so, you may want to try setting up a local website in IIS.

Comment: I tried to run the application from IIS Express. This gives the same StructureMap exception as on the production server. When I run directly from Visual Studio it works fine. What could the difference be?

Comment: @Chris We do not have a build server. I already tried to clean the solution, with the same result (working from VS, but not in IIS express on my desktop and on IIS on the server).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's an interesting problem I'll most likely hit soon..

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal I did get it to work, but I honestly can't remember it off the top of my head. I'll have a look at it on Monday.

Comment: Seeing similar behavior - would love to know how you fixed it @SteffenJørgensen. Thanks!

Comment: Anything more to share?

Comment: we had this same issue, it worked locally, but on the server it did not work.  our fix was to get rid of an old assembly reference to MVC3 in the web.config file.  It was listed in the `system.web > compilation > assemblies` section.

Comment: I seem to remember that the problem was that the .NET version on the server, did not match the version required by StructureMap.

Comment: I hit this due to System.ValueTuple missing (used by EF ... included in .NET Framework 4.7.x). Latest .NET was installed locally but not on remote web server